# State update faster than alert display

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react';

const Comp2 = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  const handleIncrease = () => {
    setCount((x) => x + 1);
  };

  const checkCurrentCount = () => {
    console.log('checking...');
    setTimeout(() => {
      alert(`Ok the current count is: ${count}`);
    }, 2000);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{count}</p>
      <button onClick={handleIncrease}>+</button>

      <button onClick={checkCurrentCount}>check count</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

### Problem

If the count number already change, but the alert shows the past number. How to encounter this problem? the setTimeout just simulation of the problem..

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem in [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-sound-iuzcz) Alerted count is updated and correct

Comment: are you sure? how about once you clicked couple times of plus button, then you click check count button..

Comment: Check the codesandbox, if you are using `setTimeout` that will be the intended behavior. Remove the `setTimeout` and try again

Comment: thats the point sir, i simulate the problem..

Comment: You don't simulate the problem, you create _a problem_. When you use `setTimeout`, it will wait 2 seconds in this example and alert the old count. There is no problem of getting the last state wtihout using the setTimeout. If you have this problem with a different code, you have to provide that code

Comment: @metalheadcoder: Can you provide a runnable example demonstrating the problem, either as a stack snippet here in the question or externally in a code sandbox?  Even with the `setTimeout` the behavior is working and correct for me.

Comment: well gentlemen.. i got this from my interview session.. i was thinking the same to remove the setTimeout, but they said they have another solution for that, some function generate a slow output and need creative solution to handle this problem.. now im stuck thinking the solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need clearTimeout and setTimeout again

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/musing-matsumoto-6tddr?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this issue with help of useRef hook.

useRef returns a mutable ref object whose .current property is initialized to the passed argument (initialValue). The returned object will persist for the full lifetime of the component.

View the solution on code sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-newton-l66q6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Another brilliant solution! Thank you @Ali Hassan!